# "This is the law of the..." – is there a general rule for this phrase?

Tags: parashat-vayikra, tzav

In Parshas Tzav, many times occures this phrase: this is the Torah of the olah, this is the Torah of the minchah, etc. Also, in other parshiyos, and it is almost always doesn't match its superficial reading.

For example, just one week ago in Parshas Vayikra we already read about introducing the basic laws of all this concepts, korbanos.

Is there a mefaresh who has some kind of meta-rule for this repetitive phrase somewhere?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.6.2?lang=bi&with=Malbim&lang2=en

Comment: The Malbim that @Shmuel posted was the first thing I looked at, and he gives a beautiful klal and answer in length (Dibur hamatchil זאת תורת העולה היא העולה). There is an interesting idea I found out, where every time (except for one) where it specifically says זאת תורת in the Torah, a Kohen is always involved. However as I mentioned there is one pasuk that doesn't fit this idea which is Vayikra 11:46 which is regarding kosher and non kosher laws. (Maybe Kohanim should be even more careful regarding eating non kosher since they are more holy than everyone else, just a thought :)

Comment: I like this idea about זאת תורת is always about Kohanim! Actually, something very similar can be found in the Artscroll Stone Chumash introduction. And this answers my question: in Parshas Vayikra, the focus is on the person bringing the korban. And in Parshas Tzav it's all about the details needed for kohanim.